# How to make PUT from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am having trouble with the put method of Web API. I am working with Kendo UI Jquery inside ASP.NET MVC and it has to make a PUT through API.

Please guide me what am I doing wrong, also at the end of this is the error code.

Here it is what I have tried so far:

API controller:

```
[HttpPut] //It never reaches here
[Route("api/Update")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(Guid id, UpdateProductCommand command)
{
    if (id != command.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    return Ok(await _mediator.Send(command));
}
```

ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult Update(Guid id, [FromBody]Product product)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44393");
            
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);

        var contentData = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = client.PutAsync("/api/Product", contentData);

        var result = response.Result;

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    return View(product);
}
```

View with Kendo UI:

```
<script>
    //----------TRANSPORT -------------------//
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        batch: false,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "https://localhost:44393/api/Product",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: "@Url.Action("Update", "Home")",
                dataType: "json",
            },
            create: {
                url: "@Url.Action("Create", "Home")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")",
                dataType: "json",

            },
           },
        pageSize: 5,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    productName: { type: "string", editable: true },
                    prouctSKU: { type: "string", editable: true },
                    productType: { type: "string", editable: true },
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Error:

> jquery.min.js:4 GET https://localhost:44385/Home/Update?id=1e8332f1-ae69-4997-b851-08d9ae81e7de&productName=sd&prouctSKU=string&productType=string 415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MVC Controller you are using `PutAsync` in a non `async` method.
Change your Action to an `async` method, change the `ActionResult` to `async Task<ActionResult>` and use the `await` keyword when calling the `PutAsync`.

Or if you do not want to change your method to an `async` method change the call `client.PutAsync` to `client.Put`

Comment: If you want to read more information about Asynchronous programming I advise you to read the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ or there is a discussion on stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your component to make a `PUT` request otherwise it will default to `GET`. According to the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.update#transportupdatetype), you should specify the `type` of the request. For example:

```
update: {
    url: "@Url.Action("Update", "Home")",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "PUT" //<---- Add this
},
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer David, already tried it but doesn't work, I think my problem may be to my MVC Controller somehow.